# What is this random name in my command-line prompt?

Tags: command-line, prompt, hostname

I'm trying to figure out what this (`obretschlt2-w7`) is, from my command-line prompt.  I'm using a `conda environment`, with the name `µ_env`, with my Username `mu`. However I can't figure out where the 2nd field is coming from.  I'm logged into a secure server VPN, through my work, but I don't ever recall seeing this.  **What is this name and where is it coming from?**

```
(µ_env) obretschlt2-w7:~ mu$ pwd
/Users/mu
```

Output from `echo $PS1`, as asked for (in comment).

```
(µ_env) \h:\W \u\$
```

Comment: please add output of `echo $PS1`.

Comment: `$ echo $PS1
(µ_env) \h:\W \u\$`

Comment: I wonder. How did you tag with hostname, but not know it was the hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that not your hostname on your system?

Try:

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

---

## Edit:

```
$ echo $PS1 (µ_env) \h:\W \u\$
```

> \h means hostname

Source: wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bash/Prompt

---

Command "hostname" may also show your hostname

Comment: `$ cat /etc/hostname
cat: /etc/hostname: No such file or directory`

Comment: |  $ echo $PS1 (µ_env) \h:\W \u\$  |


\h Hostname auf dem die Shell läuft bis zum ersten "."   | 

Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bash/Prompt/  | 

so it's your hostname. | 

Which OS do you use?

Comment: \h means hostname

Comment: command "hostname" may work to show your hostname.

Comment: obretschlt2-w7 does that mean your are using Windows 7? ;-)

Comment: `$ sw_vers
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.6
BuildVersion: 16G1510`.  I hope it's not using windows lol.

Comment: you are right!  If you add the answer I will accept it as correct.