# Why is my terminal displaying my name and then another name after it

Tags: terminal, macintosh

```
(base) shanmukhcherukumilli@Gavin-s-S23 ~ %
```

Who or what is "Gavin-s-S23"

Please let me know

Comment: Your machine name.

Comment: ... see also [What is this random name in my command-line prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482554/what-is-this-random-name-in-my-command-line-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

Your "prompt" (the whole "`(base) shanmukhcherukumilli@Gavin-s-S23 ~ %`) comes from the `$PS1` environment variable, which is usually set in your `$HOME/.bashrc`.

It is completely controllable by you, read `man bash` about `PROMPTING`. Do `echo "$PS1"`

Answer (score 0):

It's name of the computer. If you never named it that, it probably defaulted to its model number when you installed Linux. Or I'm guessing you're inside of an environment like Anaconda or something judging by the "(base)" part.